# Conditional Cancel Button on my account orders list in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, cancel-button

This is in reference to [Add Cancel button on My account Orders list using Woo Cancel for Customers Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263626/add-cancel-button-on-my-account-orders-list-using-woo-cancel-for-customers-plugi) answer:

I also tried adding the function into functions.php and also get the too few arguments error:
[image]

I did the same function provided by LoicTheAztec:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 10, 2 );
function custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses, $order ){

// Set HERE the order statuses where you want the cancel button to appear
$custom_statuses    = array( 'pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'failed' );

// Set HERE the delay (in days)
$duration = 3; // 3 days

// UPDATE: Get the order ID and the WC_Order object
if( isset($_GET['order_id']))
    $order = wc_get_order( absint( $_GET['order_id'] ) );

$delay = $duration*24*60*60; // (duration in seconds)
$date_created_time  = strtotime($order->get_date_created()); // Creation date time stamp
$date_modified_time = strtotime($order->get_date_modified()); // Modified date time stamp
$now = strtotime("now"); // Now  time stamp

// Using Creation date time stamp
if ( ( $date_created_time + $delay ) >= $now ) return $custom_statuses;
else return $statuses;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As this hook is used 2 times in the Woocommerce core code with a different number of arguments for each:
>
> - one time in [class-wc-form-handler.php *(with **one argument only***: `$statuses` *)*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Form_Handler.html#709)
> - another time in [wc-account-functions.php *(with **two arguments***: `$statuses` *and* `$order` *)*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_account_orders_actions.html#279)
>
> It's complicate to handle, without making some issue…

I have found the following turn around (a very light update) that should solve the issue:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 20, 2 );
function filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses, $order = '' ){

    // Set HERE the order statuses where you want the cancel button to appear
    $custom_statuses    = array( 'pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'failed' );

    // Set HERE the delay (in days)
    $duration = 3; // 3 days

    // UPDATE: Get the order ID and the WC_Order object
    if( ! is_object( $order ) && isset($_GET['order_id']) )
        $order = wc_get_order( absint( $_GET['order_id'] ) );

    $delay = $duration*24*60*60; // (duration in seconds)
    $date_created_time  = strtotime($order->get_date_created()); // Creation date time stamp
    $date_modified_time = strtotime($order->get_date_modified()); // Modified date time stamp
    $now = strtotime("now"); // Now  time stamp

    // Using Creation date time stamp
    if ( ( $date_created_time + $delay ) >= $now ) return $custom_statuses;
    else return $statuses;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work now.

[image]