# Add a Cancel order button to WooCommerce My account View Order pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, status

Is there a way to insert a button or link to cancel the order inside the page view-order of woocommerce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use these simple functions, where you will set the desired order statuses *(on both functions)*, to display the cancel order button on My Account Order View pages:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'custom_order_cancel_button' );
function custom_order_cancel_button( $order ) {
    $statuses = array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing', 'completed' ); // Define order statuses

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('view-order') && $order->has_status($statuses) ) {
        printf('<div style="clear:both;margin-bottom:24px;"><a href="%s" class="woocommerce-button cancel button">%s</a></div>',
            $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_endpoint_url('orders') ),
            __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel' );
function filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses ){
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('orders') ) {
        $statuses = array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing', 'completed' ); // Define order statuses
    }
    return $statuses;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

If you want this cancel button to appear also in My Account Orders list, replace the last function with:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel' );
function filter_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses ){
    $statuses = array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'processing', 'completed' ); // Define order statuses
    return $statuses;
}
```

Related: [Conditional Cancel Button on my account orders list in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164552/conditional-cancel-button-on-my-account-orders-list-in-woocommerce/50164660#50164660)